# Clearable UITextField clearing text didn't trigger shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in my `ViewController`, and the `ViewController` conforms `UITextField` `delegate`.  Every thing is fine.

I set the `UITextField` clearable mode by:

```
[myTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

The issue is, when I click the clear button of `myTextField`, the delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` cannot be triggered.  Otherwise, if I type in characters or manually delete characters one by one, it will be triggered.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
}
```

For my understanding, clear the text is an text changed event, and I want to deal with this event in a common way, i.e. in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.  But it just not work.  So, is there any way to connect to the clear text event to the `delegate` method?  All discussion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
```

this is the method called when the built-in clear button is pressed.

See the documentation for more help.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:

:)